# ROS Answers SE migration: Arm project

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you suggest a project to make a moveit / ros compatible arm?
I can 3D print parts and I have already spare components in my shelfs.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328330/arm-project/) by [Batstru](https://answers.ros.org/users/44046/batstru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try this https://www.jesseweisberg.com/moveo-with-ros

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Batstru](https://answers.ros.org/users/44046/batstru/) on 2019-07-12**:
Thanks for the answer, the one you've pointed out is something I'm definitely considering.
In addition to that I've identified also

- https://github.com/NiryoRobotics
  and this
- https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3327968

What do you think?

Cheers

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-07-13**:
The first looks quite promising but for axis 4 5 6 you nee special parts. The last one need quite mutch print time I think. But the one I pointed has also mutch Plastik.